# centOS, Jenkins, Firefox & Selenium GRID - HTTPS certificate issue

Tags: firefox, https, jenkins, selenium-grid

I have Jenkins running headless on a remote machine(centOS). I am trying to run some automated login tests using Selenium Grid (with both hub and a node on same centOS machine) on a development environment whose security certificate is self signed. So, on the  home page, when the login link is clicked, it lands up at https error page, while selenium webdriver expects the login page. So all tests are getting failed. I tried to create firefox profile:

```
    nodeUrl = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";   
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);               
    profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

    capability.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    capability.setBrowserName("firefox"); 
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capability);
```

But this does not work out. How can i make sure that when the node invokes firefox, it accept that untrusted certificate?